# Passing multiple arrays into a function as arguments

Tags: javascript

In my maze game app, I have a function which changes the walls in the maze by adding/removing borders. This is the way I have done this up until this point:

In my gameView.js file:

```
export const changeWalls = (addOrRemove, side, ...boxes) => {
    const boxEls = getBoxArrEl(...boxes);
    boxEls.forEach((e) => {
        if(addOrRemove === "add") {
            e.classList.add(side);
        } else {
            e.classList.remove(side);
        }
    });
};
```

In my Index.js (controller) file:

```
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, strings.borderLeft, 15, 6);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, strings.borderTop, 28);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, strings.borderRight, 5, 14);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, strings.borderBottom, 22);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.remove, strings.borderBottom, 8);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.remove, strings.borderRight, 4, 21, 28);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.remove, strings.borderTop, 14);
    gameView.changeWalls(strings.remove, strings.borderLeft, 5, 22, 29);
```

The above code is just a small snippet of the many wall changes as this is repeated every 1.5 seconds. As you can see, this is not a very elegant way of doing this and does not really follow the 'DRY' principles.

As a solution to this, I am trying to think of a way I can re-create the above by using destructuring, combined with the rest parameter. I am trying to achieve something like this (gameView.js file):

```
export const changeWallsAdd = ([side, ...boxes]) => {
    const boxEls = getBoxArrEl(...boxes);
    boxEls.forEach((e) => {
            e.classList.add(side);
    });
};

export const changeWallsRemove = ([side, ...boxes]) => {
    const boxEls = getBoxArrEl(...boxes);
    boxEls.forEach((e) => {
            e.classList.remove(side);
    });
};
```

index.js file:

```
 gameView.changeWallsAdd(
[strings.borderLeft, 15, 6], 
[strings.borderTop, 28], 
[strings.borderRight, 5, 14], 
[strings.borderBottom, 22]);
    
     gameView.changeWallsRemove(
[strings.borderBottom, 8], 
[strings.borderRight, 4, 21, 28], 
[strings.borderTop, 14], 
[strings.borderLeft, 5, 22, 29]);
```

The above code works for the first parameters that are passed in ([strings.borderLeft, 15, 6] & [strings.borderBottom, 8]) but not the following ones. I wasn't expecting this to work to be honest but I just wanted to show what I was trying to achieve.

Any ideas about how I could achieve something like this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to pass multidimentinal array like so `var walls = [ [first array],[second one],[third one], ... ]` and loop throught them in the receptive function.

Comment: Yeah I think you might be on the right track. I think I need to loop through the array of arrays and call the changeWallsAdd/changeWallsRemove methods on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to pass the all the border as one:

```js
export const changeWalls = (addOrRemove, bordersBoxes) => {
    Object.keys(bordersBoxes).forEach((side) => {
      const boxEls = getBoxArrEl(bordersBoxes[side]);
      boxEls.forEach((e) => {
        if(addOrRemove === "add") {
            e.classList.add(side);
        } else {
            e.classList.remove(side);
        }
      });
    });
};
    
    
  gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, {
    strings.borderLeft: [15, 6],
    strings.borderTop: [28],
    strings.borderRight: [5, 14],
    strings.borderBottom: [22]
  });
```

Also, it will allow you to be able to change only one or more border with the same function.

*more details*:

You can pass an object (in this case a sort of map) that will use as key the border name and as value the array of the boxes you need to change.
Because it does not contains hardcoded checks, the object can also miss some properties:

```
  gameView.changeWalls(strings.add, {
    strings.borderLeft: [15, 6],
    strings.borderBottom: [22]
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this Greedo. Forgive my ignorance, I am fairly new to JavaScript. Would you mind explaining what's happening here?

Comment: I added a small explaination

Comment: Thank you for this